# Is it normal for my sump pump to run so often? If not, who should I call?

Tags: plumbing, sump-pump

My sump pit has water leaking into it, coming through the plastic wall. I circled the portion that has water coming through it in the picture below. I just noticed it's pumping water every few minutes but this is after we had a lot of rain. Is that normal?

[image]

Comment: It's hard to say if this is normal or not.  Is the water constantly flowing and thus the pump is constantly on? Or is this happening after a rain storm?  Water is supposed to flow into the sump hole and be pumped out - that's normal behavior.  But if it never stops flowing and the pump is constantly running then maybe there is a broken water pipe somewhere?

Comment: I just noticed it after we had a lot of rain. I'm going to wait and see if it stops after a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like you have a hole in your pit liner. but its doing its job  its still removing water from under the foundation as it should. however i advise you to call a reputable drain inspection service to do a video inspection of the footing drain those are the two pipes you see entering the pit. if water is leaking into the pit from a hole in the plastic liner it should also be coming into  it from the two pipes that enter the pit.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely normal and doing what it's supposed to: collect and discharge the water under your house. I'd say my sump runs about once every 3~6 hours, regardless. And as much as every half an hour or more during a good rain.

Obviously if you suspect foul play you should call the professionals at 1-800 GHOSTBUSTERS.